# Braintree Drop-In UI in ASP.NET web form with submit button method is not called when clicked

Tags: asp.net, webforms, braintree

I have created a simple payment form where contains fields that accept amount, the drop-in UI and the submit button.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
  <label>Amount:</label>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server" />
</div>
<div id="dropin-container"></div>
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Submit" />
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>
<script>
  braintree.setup("<%= this.ClientToken %>", "dropin", { container: "dropin-container" });
</script>
```

and the code behind

```
protected string ClientToken = String.Empty;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        GenerateClientToken();
    }
}

protected void GenerateClientToken()
{
    var gateway = new BraintreeGateway
    {
        Environment = Braintree.Environment.SANDBOX,
        MerchantId = "merchant-id",
        PublicKey = "public-key",
        PrivateKey = "private-key"
    };

    this.ClientToken = gateway.ClientToken.generate();
}

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var gateway = new BraintreeGateway
    {
        Environment = Braintree.Environment.SANDBOX,
        MerchantId = "merchant-id",
        PublicKey = "public-key",
        PrivateKey = "private-key"
    };

    var request = new TransactionRequest
    {
        Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(this.txtAmount.Text),
        PaymentMethodNonce = Request.Form["payment_method_nonce"]
    };

    Result<Transaction> result = gateway.Transaction.Sale(request);
}
```

After I load the page in the browser, I can see the form that accept amount and also the drop-in ui form which accept credit card and/or PayPal.

The issue is when I click Submit button, the method btnSubmit_Click doesn't get called. The page looks like it post back correctly but I cannot see any line of code within the btnSubmit_Click is executed.

I follow the instruction from this page:
https://www.braintreepayments.com/features/drop-in

But I really can't think of anything that I miss.

Anyone can help me with this issue would be very appreciated. Thank you so much.

Knott

Answer (score 3):

I work at Braintree and can help you with this question.

Some background on what braintree.js is doing when you load the Drop-in on your page: it listens for form submissions, and when it detects one it will interrupt the form submit, communicate with Braintree to generate a nonce, and then run your callback if defined. What’s happening is that your .NET postback event is broadcasting a submit action – the same type of action that braintree.js interrupts in the first place.

As a workaround, you can try adding the following to your Page_Load code:

```
ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, string.Empty);
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "PayEvent","<script>function PayEvent() {document.getElementById('__EVENTTARGET').value = '"+ btnSubmit.ClientID +"'; }</script>" );
btnSubmit.Attributes.Add("onClick", "PayEvent()");
```

Where btnSubmit is the ID of your button.

This should circumvent the submit interruption and allow your form to be submitted properly. In addition, this problem does not occur with our [custom integration](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+dotnet/guides/credit-cards#client-side-integration) as an alternative.

Let us know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Hi Brian, I am wondering what the first line of your code do? it looks like it's call to get something and that method return a string. But it does not assign to any variable or being used later.

Answer (score 0):

You just needed to put your transaction request code in a method and then call that sub on a post back rather than page load.

This way the auto submit won't interrupt with things.

```
Protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
    GetClientToken();
} else {
    Pay();
}
}

protected void Pay() {        
    PaymentMethodNonce = Request.Form["payment_method_nonce"]        
    //Build request string etc.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Brian,

Your solution above was supplied to me by PayPal support, but unfortunately, it doesn't solve the problem.

To be honest, it is this 'listening' (read: unreliable, 'clever code') to form submissions which is causing all the problems when one tries to integrate it in a Web Forms/UpdatePanel page - it really isn't designed for WebForms/UpdatePanels and requires all kinds of really messy code to make it work and synchronise properly. It is almost as if it was never designed for anything other than MVC or Java!

What would be a far better solution would be if we could attach a JavaScript call in OnClientClick of a button which synchronously calls BrainTree/PayPal via a JavaScript module hosted on PayPal which returns the nonce so that we can then do something with it. As it stands now, the Braintree/PayPal code intercepts a submit button (all buttons in WebForms are 'submits' by default, so this causes problems) and fires off a call asynchronously to get a nonce and at the same time, calls the button OnClick in the C# code. The net result is that the C# code runs before the Braintree/PayPal call returns and you can never synchronise the two.

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's a response to an answer.

Comment: Yes, I did resolve it. The PayPal/Braintree code is evidently not designed to work with WebForms because it intercepts the WebForms postback system to perform its own asynchronous activity and doesn't re-synchronise so it completes at different times to the webforms postback system. Basically, it is unusable. What I did in the end was use JavaScript in the PayPal/Braintree script to get the nonce, receive it back, put it into a WebForms hidden field and then activate the save button. When the C# code runs, it received the nonce from the hidden field and was then able to do what I wanted to do.

Comment: @Graham - would you care to share your code? You're certainly not the only one trying to integrate Braintree with Web Forms.